# How do I find out my Action on Google "homepage"

Tags: actions-on-google

I just watched the [Building Apps for the Google Assistant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y26vvxCb3zE&feature=youtu.be&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKC8eODk_RNCWv3fBcLvMMy). The share option which was in the presentation is missing on my device. How can I find my url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how I can find my ID. Sign in into the [Google on Actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/) open the web developer tools and check the network traffic when you click on your actual action:

[image]

Here you can see my ID is "id/61bad4b884603b22". So your url will be: https://assistant.google.com/services/a/id/61bad4b884603b22/

Answer (score 0):

The share link will be available in the directory listing. (The rollout of it was delayed slightly, but should be there "soon".)

Answer (score 0):

Good find, hopefully the more obvious "View in the Directory" link will be rolling you to your soon.

[image: view in directly link]